# Linux Android ADB and AVD emulator connections

Tags: linux, adb, android-virtual-device

Right now, I have my Android SDK and ADB set it up on my Linux system. I have created an emulator under Android AVD Manager and it runs. The problem is that I am trying to connect to an emulator using ADB shell but every time when I do

```
 adb devices
```

there is nothing being listed under the command. But when I physically connect an Android device into a computer, adb is able to recognize the physical device.

I have tried

```
adb kill-server
```

and

```
adb start-server
```

I have also ran everything under ROOT privileges and can't happen to narrow down what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, please enable "USB Debugging" in the the emulated Android instance.  If you already have, what is the output of `lsusb`?  Are the ports open?  Scan 5037 and 5500-5600 on the emulators IP address (assuming you are using a UNIX-based OS and have networking enabled in the emulator).

(see also: https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have resolved myself. The problem was that "adb" from command line that I used was referring to different adb path. It worked by running "adb" directly from platform-tools folder. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad you got it working either way.